# I am getting a RoutingError for a GET request looking for a file /sw/js

Tags: ruby-on-rails, api, routes

I am going to a URL endpoint that is rendering a JSON response, yet I see this error in my rails s logs:

```
Started GET "/sw.js" for 127.0.0.1 at 2018-10-15 11:32:50 -0400

ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/sw.js"):

actionpack (5.2.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:65:in `call'
web-console (3.7.0) lib/web_console/middleware.rb:135:in `call_app'
web-console (3.7.0) lib/web_console/middleware.rb:30:in `block in call'
web-console (3.7.0) lib/web_console/middleware.rb:20:in `catch'
web-console (3.7.0) lib/web_console/middleware.rb:20:in `call'
```

Where exactly could this be coming from?

I create a new rails 5.x app yesterday, and I am not sure where this file is being referenced from.

I don't even have a layout for this controller either.

rake routes:

```
               api_boards GET  /api/boards(.:format)                                                                    api/boards#index
                api_board GET  /api/boards/:id(.:format)                                                                api/boards#show
       rails_service_blob GET  /rails/active_storage/blobs/:signed_id/*filename(.:format)                               active_storage/blobs#show
rails_blob_representation GET  /rails/active_storage/representations/:signed_blob_id/:variation_key/*filename(.:format) active_storage/representations#show
       rails_disk_service GET  /rails/active_storage/disk/:encoded_key/*filename(.:format)                              active_storage/disk#show
update_rails_disk_service PUT  /rails/active_storage/disk/:encoded_token(.:format)                                      active_storage/disk#update
     rails_direct_uploads POST /rails/active_storage/direct_uploads(.:format)                                           active_storage/direct_uploads#create
```

Comment: Can you print here the result of `bundle exec rake routes` command ?

Comment: @Uelb updated with that info

Comment: Can you also paste your gemfile, I think a library is injecting the call, maybe sw stands for service worker ?

Comment: Sounds like something do with with react.